# Java, merge sort

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I have been trying to code merge sort, without creating additional arrays for keeping sorted parts, after few hours I can't find the error, which causes last bit of the array to be sorted in a wrong order. Theres quite a few helper methods, I used for the debugging, I left them in.

```
public class Sorter2
{

    public static void toString(int [] list)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list[i]);
            if(!(i + 1 == list.length))
            {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void toString(int list[], int from, int to)
    {
        for(int i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list[i]);
            if(i + 1 <= to)
            {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }


    public static void insertAt(int [] list, int insert_at, int taken_from)
    {
        int to_insert = list[taken_from];
        for(int i = taken_from; i >= insert_at; i--)
        {
            if(i != insert_at)
            {
                list[i] = list[i - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                list[i] = to_insert;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sortSegments(int [] list ,int segment_one_begin, int segment_one_end, int segment_two_begin, int segment_two_end)
    {
        toString(list, segment_one_begin, segment_two_end);
        int sorted = 0;
        for(int i = segment_two_begin; i <= segment_two_end; i++)
        {
            for(int l = segment_one_begin + sorted; l <= segment_one_end; l++)
            {
                if(list[i] <= list[l])
                {
                    insertAt(list, l, i);
                    sorted++;
                }
            }
        }
        toString(list, segment_one_begin, segment_two_end);
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int [] list, int segment_begining, int segment_end)
    {
        if(segment_end - segment_begining < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int midpoint = (segment_end + segment_begining) / 2;

            mergeSort(list, segment_begining, midpoint);
            mergeSort(list, midpoint + 1, segment_end);
            sortSegments(list, segment_begining, midpoint, midpoint + 1, segment_end);

        }

    }
    public static void mergeSort(int [] list)
    {
        mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    public static boolean isInOrder(int [] toCheck)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < toCheck.length; i++)
        {
            if(toCheck[i] < toCheck[i - 1])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static int [] populate(int numOfItems)
    {
        int [] toReturn = new int[numOfItems];

        for(int i = 0; i < toReturn.length; i++)
        {
            toReturn[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] nums = populate(20);
        mergeSort(nums);
        toString(nums);
        System.out.println(isInOrder(nums));

    }
}
```

Comment: Find a merge sort implementation here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's adjust your code a bit so that the tests would be reproducible, and we could see the whole process:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Sorter2 {
    public static final Random RANDOM = new Random(55);

    public static void toString(int[] list) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }

    public static void toString(int list[], int from, int to) {
        System.out.print(from + "\t" + to + "\t");
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i]);
            if (i + 1 <= to) {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }


    public static void insertAt(int[] list, int insert_at, int taken_from) {
        int to_insert = list[taken_from];
        for (int i = taken_from; i >= insert_at; i--) {
            if (i != insert_at) {
                list[i] = list[i - 1];
            } else {
                list[i] = to_insert;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sortSegments(int[] list, int segment_one_begin, int segment_one_end, int segment_two_begin, int segment_two_end) {
        System.out.println("Sorter2.sortSegments("+segment_one_begin + "," + segment_one_end + "," + segment_two_begin + "," + segment_two_end + ")");
        toString(list, segment_one_begin, segment_two_end);
        int sorted = 0;
        for (int i = segment_two_begin; i <= segment_two_end; i++) {
            for (int l = segment_one_begin + sorted; l <= segment_one_end; l++) {
                if (list[i] <= list[l]) {
                    insertAt(list, l, i);
                    sorted++;
                }
            }
        }
        toString(list, segment_one_begin, segment_two_end);
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] list, int segment_begining, int segment_end) {
        if (segment_end - segment_begining < 1) {
            return;
        }

        int midpoint = (segment_end + segment_begining) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, segment_begining, midpoint);
        mergeSort(list, midpoint + 1, segment_end);
        sortSegments(list, segment_begining, midpoint, midpoint + 1, segment_end);
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] list) {
        mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    public static boolean isInOrder(int[] toCheck) {
        for (int i = 1; i < toCheck.length; i++) {
            if (toCheck[i] < toCheck[i - 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static int[] populate(int numOfItems) {
        int[] toReturn = new int[numOfItems];

        for (int i = 0; i < toReturn.length; i++) {
            toReturn[i] = (int) (nextRandom() * 100 + 1);
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    private static double nextRandom() {
        return RANDOM.nextDouble();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = populate(20);
        mergeSort(nums);
        toString(nums);
        System.out.println(isInOrder(nums));
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,0,1,1)
0   1   73,47
0   1   47,73
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,1,2,2)
0   2   47,73,48
0   2   47,48,73
Sorter2.sortSegments(3,3,4,4)
3   4   42,64
3   4   42,64
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,2,3,4)
0   4   47,48,73,42,64
0   4   42,47,48,73,64
Sorter2.sortSegments(5,5,6,6)
5   6   12,38
5   6   12,38
Sorter2.sortSegments(5,6,7,7)
5   7   12,38,14
5   7   12,14,38
Sorter2.sortSegments(8,8,9,9)
8   9   18,87
8   9   18,87
Sorter2.sortSegments(5,7,8,9)
5   9   12,14,38,18,87
5   9   12,14,18,38,87
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,4,5,9)
0   9   42,47,48,73,64,12,14,18,38,87
0   9   12,42,14,18,38,47,48,64,73,87
Sorter2.sortSegments(10,10,11,11)
10  11  60,29
10  11  29,60
Sorter2.sortSegments(10,11,12,12)
10  12  29,60,95
10  12  29,60,95
Sorter2.sortSegments(13,13,14,14)
13  14  21,37
13  14  21,37
Sorter2.sortSegments(10,12,13,14)
10  14  29,60,95,21,37
10  14  21,29,37,60,95
Sorter2.sortSegments(15,15,16,16)
15  16  28,66
15  16  28,66
Sorter2.sortSegments(15,16,17,17)
15  17  28,66,73
15  17  28,66,73
Sorter2.sortSegments(18,18,19,19)
18  19  80,69
18  19  69,80
Sorter2.sortSegments(15,17,18,19)
15  19  28,66,73,69,80
15  19  28,66,69,73,80
Sorter2.sortSegments(10,14,15,19)
10  19  21,29,37,60,95,28,66,69,73,80
10  19  21,28,29,37,60,95,66,69,73,80
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,9,10,19)
0   19  12,42,14,18,38,47,48,64,73,87,21,28,29,37,60,95,66,69,73,80
0   19  12,21,28,29,37,42,14,18,38,47,48,64,73,87,60,95,66,69,73,80
12,21,28,29,37,42,14,18,38,47,48,64,73,87,60,95,66,69,73,80
false
```

As you can see, the first problem manifests itself in the following lines:

```
Sorter2.sortSegments(0,2,3,4)
0   4   47,48,73,42,64
0   4   42,47,48,73,64
```

We take two ordered chunks and get an unordered chunk as a result. Put a breakpoint on line `for (int i = segment_two_begin; i <= segment_two_end; i++) {` and try to catch the case for `Sorter2.sortSegments(0,2,3,4)`:

- `42 <= 47`, so we call `insertAt` to move 42 before 47
- but that means 73 is now in `segment_two`—and believed to be in place!

Here's the error for you: your `sortSegments` does not work as advertised.

If you think a minute about that method, you'll find that you do not actually need nested loops: all you need is to find the necessary elements, step by step. So you're better off with one cycle from `segment_one_begin` to `segment_two_end`, and a pointer to a current position in the second list: if an element from first list is lower than one from the second, you just skip to the new position. If it's not, you perform the shift you need—and move a pointer.

I've made a fix and it works just fine for me—so it seems is was the only error in your implementation. If you're still stuck, please describe your problem, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Actually, I do have a question, when I want change order of numbers, what I do is I shift numbers to the right, and then insert, does that affect the runtime, comparing to lets say having separate array, saving sorted sequence there and then replacing it in the original array? Is there a better way of coding it, without having trading off too much time or memory?

Comment: It does indeed. In the worst case, when the list is initially sorted in a descending order, each step involves as many shifts as there are elements in the second part—say, `k`. The shift in turn takes `O(k)`, so that means the last merge alone will take O(1/4 n^2)—so long for O(n log n). Check [Katajainen, Pasanen & Teuhola 1996](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#CITEREFKatajainenPasanenTeuhola1996) for an in-place O(n log n) version.

Comment: So what would be a better option? Helper array?

Comment: Depends on your goals. If you are doing a home work, a helper array is the standard solution. If you want to have an in-place merge sort, the solution is in the article (some links are broken indeed, but http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.8523 worked for me).

Comment: Can you tell me what the error is, I simply can't fix that.http://pastebin.com/m1zuCsqD new version. If I get this to work, would that be  O(n log n)?

Comment: Should be fine; way too verbose to my test, but looks reasonable, looks like O(n log n). Try it on a million-element array: if it finishes within a minute, you're ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, found the error and fixed that sort!

http://pastebin.com/UJ3dFfrN

Is that nLogn?

Comment: please edit your question and not create "answers". Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I am new around here :P

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int[] t;

    public static void merge(int[] a, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) t[k] = a[k];
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if (i > mid) a[k] = t[j++];
            else if (j > hi) a[k] = t[i++];
            else if (t[j] < t[i]) {
                a[k] = t[j++];
            } else a[k] = t[i++];
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        t = new int[a.length];
        sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        if (lo >= hi) return;
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, lo, mid);
        sort(a, mid + 1, hi);
        merge(a, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        sort(arr);
    }
```

}